# rails nested resource and routes for initialized resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, form-for, nested-routes, nested-form-for

I have a problem with the normal way rails operates when using nested forms / resources and routing.

I have two tables, Words and Definitions...

Words have many definitions, but I do not create a Word until it has at least one definition.

Everything on the model and controller end works but I cannot figure out how to handle the form helpers.

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@word, @definition] do |f| %>
```

This works perfectly but only if @word actually exists and is not a new UNSAVED record.  IE in the controller I am doing a `find_or_initialize_by` call for Word then building a definition off of that.

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:word, @definition] do |f| %>
```

This words but only if the word doesn't exist.  IE if I try to edit using this construction I get an odd url (which doesn't work).  `words/12345/definition/12345`

I tried using the `url_for` helper but had similar results as above...

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't initialize embedded documents by default.  You need to build them yourself most likely with a callback in your `Word` model:

```
after_initialize :build_definition

def build_definition
  self.definitions.build unless self.definitions.any?
end
```

Comment: It works, but I noticed later it causes a lot of other problems too. I can no longer use @word.definitions.blank?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna stay CRUD and allow definitions to be created before words, you must duplicate routes for definitions, one inside words and one outside, so you can do:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@definition] do |f| %>
```